# JAVA load List of files other way

Tags: java, file, maven, load

Hello guys i am Java amater so be nice please :) . I want to load my list of files as i load my pictures.

```
Image playerImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imgs/janosikos.png"));
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(playerImg);
```

Because i am using maven to create build my program i have to change all paths to be relative.

i right now i am loading files like this.

```
File folder = new File("src/main/resources/levels/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

and like this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/main/resources/levels/"+fileName));
```

i know for advanced java programme this is primitive question but i am really strugging. Thanks for help.

so i want to load files like

```
FileReader("/levels/"+fileName));
```

Comment: The use of Maven does not require any change to your code.  In fact, `getResourceAsStream` is designed to work with .jar files as well as with code and resources in regular directories.

Comment: yes but now i am using path "src/main/resources/levels/" witch in jar file doesnt exist i need to use somethink like i used with picutres.
File folder = new File(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/levels/"));
i tried this but file cant have input stream as parameter

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question.  I got the impression you were already using `getResourceAsStream` to load images.  Why do you want to switch to using the File class?

Comment: i am using `getResourceAsStream` to load images to my application but when i build jar folder my file paths didnt exist so i have to change loading my files. and for example i used my code from loading pictures.

Comment: i mean i have to load images and another files. Both shuldnt contain path like "src/main/sesources/"

Comment: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/levels/" + fileName)` should be sufficient.  Maven uses the `src/main/resources` directory as the root of all data files which are to be placed in your .jar file.  Note that you can use an IDE (or any basic zip tool) to examine a .jar file and see the structure for yourself, since a .jar file is actually a zip file with a different extension.